# How to extract GUID using regular extractor in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

How to extract the guid `6d801db8_03b7_497e_b9d1_f54bdad496f5` from `cheapestselectionprice="price_6d801db8_03b7_497e_b9d1_f54bdad496f5">` using regular expression extractor in jmeter?

```
<div style="padding-left: 30px; background-color: #ffffff">
    <table id="table_b27525f8_b483_4dbd_a628_9f45be92c933" class="table" lowestprice="&amp;#163;72" cheapestselectionprice="price_6d801db8_03b7_497e_b9d1_f54bdad496f5">
        <thead>
            <tr style="height: 4px">
                <th colspan="4" class="outboundHeaderRowBg"></th>
```

I know I need to use 2 regular expression extractors but for the first I am using `cheapestselectionprice=(price_[^a-z,A-Z,0-9,_]*)` but seems not getting any thing.

Comment: Have you tried `cheapestselectionprice=("price_[^a-z,A-Z,0-9,_]*")`

Comment: No, its returning no match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex = "cheapestselectionprice=\"price_([^"]+)"
```

`\"` escapes `"`
`(...)` is a capturing group
`[^"]+` 1 or more characters not equal to `"`, aka all characters until the next `"`

Comment: No it is also not returning any results. Also problem is there are so many prices but i want to select only that has cheapestselectionprice.

Comment: @sam Changed to include `cheapestselctionprice`.  It should be returning results, I'm really tired, but the regex is correct.  You're most likely using a function that matches to the whole string or beginning of the string or something, instead of a function that searches throughout the string.

Comment: many thanks. Yes tried with cheapestselectionprice="price_([^"]+)" and it is working great...Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = "cheapestselectionprice=\"price_(.+)"
```

Comment: consider adding some explanation